# value only displaying from echo

Tags: php, wordpress

This is probably a really simple question and Im sorry if it is. However I have been searching and cannot see a solution.

I am using wordpress as a CMS and am enqueue google fonts based on a variable as so

```
if (!function_exists('opd_load_google_style'))  {
    /* Add Google Fonts */
    global $opd_albaband;
    $google_font = $opd_albaband['typography_h1']['font-family'];

    function opd_load_google_style() {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_register_style('googleFont','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$google_font.' 400,700');
            wp_enqueue_style('ggl', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('googleFont') );
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'opd_load_google_style');
}
```

However this produces a Undefined variable `$google_font`. I can get `$google_font` to display using `echo $google_font` but this would not work with `wp_register_style`...

Am I missing something? Sorry for its simplicity.

Comment: Read up about variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$google_font` variable is out of scope so you can't useit in your `opd_load_google_style` function.  Instead your code should look like this

```
if (!function_exists('opd_load_google_style'))  {

    function opd_load_google_style() {

        /* Add Google Fonts */
        global $opd_albaband;
        $google_font = $opd_albaband['typography_h1']['font-family'];

        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_register_style('googleFont','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$google_font.' 400,700');
            wp_enqueue_style('ggl', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('googleFont') );
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'opd_load_google_style');
}
```

Or you could pass the `$google_font` variable to your function by doing

```
function opd_load_google_style($google_font) {
    //Inside your function you now have access to $google_font
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to shuffle things around a bit, as your `opd_load_google_style` function does not have access to `$google_font`.

```
if (!function_exists('opd_load_google_style'))  {
    function opd_load_google_style() {
        /* Add Google Fonts */
        global $opd_albaband;

        $google_font = $opd_albaband['typography_h1']['font-family'];
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_register_style('googleFont','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$google_font.' 400,700');
            wp_enqueue_style('ggl', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('googleFont') );
        }
    }
}
```